# Local Kronecker-Weber implies Global

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm having some trouble understanding how Local Kronecker-Weber Theorem implies Kronecker-Weber Theorem (Sutherland's proof). I have essentially two doubts. The proof goes as follows:

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a finite abelian extension. For every prime rational prime $p$ that ramifies in $K$, we take a prime $\mathfrak{p}\mid p$ in $K$, and consider the completion $K_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathbb{Q}_p$. By Local Kronecker-Weber, there exists some positive integer $n_p$ such that $K_{\mathfrak{p}}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{n_p})$. Define $e_p=v_p(n_p)$ and $n=\prod_{p\text{ ramifies in }K}p^{e_p}$. We define $L=K(\zeta_n)$, and we want to prove that $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. For each $p$ we pick a prime $\mathfrak{P}\mid \mathfrak{p}$ in $L$.

The first problem is: let $F_{\mathfrak{P}}$ be the maximal unramified subextension of $L_{\mathfrak{P}}/\mathbb{Q}_p$. The book states that $K_{\mathfrak{p}}\subseteq F_{\mathfrak{P}}(\zeta_{p^{e_p}})$, and I don't see how I can prove it. Since $p\nmid n_p/p^{e_p}$, the extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{n_p/p^{e_p}})/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is unramified, then it would suffice to prove that $\zeta_{n_p/p^{e_p}}\in L_{\mathfrak{P}}$, but I can't.

The second problem is to prove that every rational prime that ramifies in $L$ also ramifies in $K$, a fact that the book also uses. However, I can't see why it is not possible that ramification occurs in $L/K$.

Comment: The first claim is an immediate consequence of the maximality condition. The second claim follows from the definition of $n$: primes ramified in $L/K$ lie above a prime dividing $n$ by definition.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? The first claim will indeed follow immediately IF I could prove that $\zeta_{n_p/p^{e_p))$ is in $L_{\mathfrak{P}}$. As to the second claim, could you explain how this works, or indicate some source where I can find this result? I think you are using some fact about ramification that I don't know.

Comment: The only result you need is that a prime $p$ ramifies in ${\mathbb Q}(\zeta_m)$ (with $m \not\equiv 2 \bmod 4$) if and only if $p  \mid m$ (or rather the corresponding local result).

Comment: I thought about it, but the problem is that the base field is $K$ and not $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

For the second question, see that $L = K\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ (composite field), and a prime $p$ ramifies in $L$ if and only if it ramifies in either $K$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. Then the result Franz mentioned, along with how we defined $n$, proves that only the primes ramifying in $L$ are exactly the primes ramified in $K$.

Comment: The problem in the first question is: do I know that $n_p/p^{e_p}$ divides $n$? I don't see why $n_p$ couldn't have prime factors that $n$ doesn't. 
As for the second question, I didn't know this result about ramification of primes in a composite field. Could you give me some reference?

Comment: You're completely right regarding the first question, and I have edited my answer accordingly. For the reference, I learned it first from Marcus' "Number Fields", Theorem 31.